# variable timestep and acceleration

Tags: c, math, physics

To move objects with a variable time step I just have to do:

```
ship.position += ship.velocity * deltaTime;
```

But when I try this with:

```
ship.velocity += ship.power * deltaTime;
```

I get different results with different time steps. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I am modelling an object falling to the ground on one axis with a single fixed force (gravity) acting on it.

Comment: How are the results it different? If you set the time step to a very small number then you should get good results. Does that work for you? Please  show some code? It is difficult to help you.

Comment: @nielsle I made a testcase here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/554854/ This seems to work perfectly with 1ms time-step and 100ms. So I have no idea what i was doing wrong before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ship.position = ship.position + ship.velocity * deltaTime + 0.5 * ship.power * deltaTime ^ 2;
ship.velocity += ship.power * deltaTime;
```

http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math101/notes/applications/velocity.html

The velocity part of your equations is correct and they must both be updated at every time step.

This all assumes that you have constant power (acceleration) over the deltaTime as pointed out by belisarius.

Comment: but your not changing ship.velocity?

Comment: The velocity equation in the question is correct, unless the acceleration is non-constant over deltaTime.

Comment: Brian I can't wrap my heads around ship.velocity not changing. Could you look at my current function and see what I mean? http://paste.ubuntu.com/554516/

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. You need to update both velocity and position at every step. The velocity equation you had to start with was correct. I've updated my answer include velocity.

Comment: You should roll back your correction -- you got it right first, and now it is wrong.  The first equation (in the current version of your answer) describes the motion completely, with `ship.velocity` being the initial speed of the ship.  The initial speed never changes, of course.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: No, it's fine - Brian is calculating the position change over each timestep, and the initial velocity for the next timestep is equal to the final velocity for the current timestep.

Comment: @caf: Thanks. I interpreted `deltaTime` to be the absolute time, not the time step, hence the confusion.

Comment: @Brian You are welcome to use my suggestions. You should credit the source, though.

Comment: Sorry belisarius. I did only think about the acceleration needing being constant after reading your post and got that from you. I'll note that.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing (mathematically) is evaluating integrals. In the first case, the linear approximation is exact, as you have a linear relationship.

In the second case, you have at least a parabola, so your results are only approximate. You may get better results by using a smaller deltaTime, or by using the real integral equations, if available.

**Edit**

Brian's answer is right as long as the ship.power remains always constant, and you recalculate ship.velocity at each step. It is indeed the integral equation for a constant accelerated movement.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inherent problem trying to integrate numerically. There will be an error. Lowering delta will give you more accurate results, but more computation is needed. If your power function is integrable, you could try that.

Comment: Or you can stick with larger timesteps and use a higher order integration scheme (say 2nd (or higher) order Runga-Kutta)....

Answer (score 1):

Your simulation is numerically solving the equation of motion for a single mass point.  The time discretisation you are using is called ["Euler method"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), and it is possible to show that it does not preserve energy (as the exact solution does in some way).  A much better yet simple way of solving equations of motion is the ["leapfrog integration"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration).

Comment: I think that it is difficult to see from his code if he is already using the leapfrog method. We need more code before we can judge.

Comment: @nielsle: He obviously is not -- it would solve the case of constant acceleration exactly.

Comment: The equations for leapfrog integration are
x[i+1] = x[i] + v[i+1/3 ]*dt

Comment: @nielsle: It's 1/2 instead of 1/3 -- see the Wikipedia link.  But my point was that the OP observed that his solution changed depending on the timestep even for constant acceleration.  This simply would not happen if he would have used leapfrog integration, because you get the exact solution regardless of the timestep for this case.  So we can tell he did not use leapfrog integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Verlet integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet) to calculate position and velocity of object. Acceleration you can calculate from a = m*F where m is mass and F is force. This is one of the easiest algorithm

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use setInterval(moveBoxes,20) to update the boxes, and subsequently you use (new Date()).getTime()) to calculate deltaT. This is somewhat redundant, because you could have used the number 20 to calculate deltaT directly.

It is better write the code so that you use exacly the same value for deltaT during each time step.  (In other words deltaT should not depend on the value  of (new Date()).getTime())). This way your code becomes  reproducible and it is easier for you to write unit tests.

Let us look at a situation where the browser has less CPU-time available for a short time interval. In this situation you want to avoid long term effects on the dynamics. One the lack of CPU-time is over you want the browser to return to a state that is unaffected by the short lack of CPU-time. You  can achieve this by using the same value of deltaT in each time step.

By the way. I think that the following code

```
if(box.x < 0) {
        box.x = 0;
        box.vx *= -1;
    }
```

Could be replaced with

```
if(box.x < 0) {
        box.x *= -1 ;
        box.vx *= -1;
    }
```

Good luck with the project - and please include code samples in the first version of your question next time you ask :-)

Comment: I was finding that on some browsers (Internet explorer) drawing the moving elements was slower than the interval. Hence the need for variable time steps.

Comment: I see you point.  In that case I would prefer to add some code that detected the slowness of the browser and increased deltaT to a new constant value.   If all the CPU-time is spend drawing of the graphics, then you could perhaps let your differential equation solver take several time steps between each update of the graphics.